# How should bulk DME be stored?

Tags: beer, extract, storage

Related to this [question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-should-bulk-grain-be-stored), but I'd like to get a 50 lb. bag of pilsner DME from the LHBS to use over the course of 3-6 months. Can it be stored like grain, or are there additional considerations that need to be taken into account?

Comment: I didn't realize they sold bags of DME that large!

Comment: What can I say? My LHBS rocks! http://brewhut.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd hazard a guess that in addition to moisture, you might be also be concerned with oxidation. I've seen longer term storage of grains in 5 gallon pails with a nice tight seal work well; apparently a long-term storage trick is to put dry-ice in the bottom of the pail before filling, thus displacing all the oxygen in the bucket. This would also have the side-affect of removing all the moisture as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the main thing you're concerned with is moisture, just as with grain, so storing in airtight containers is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd ask the store what they suggest.  People who buy this have probably told them their good ideas of how they handle it.

Wow, that's a lot of DME.  Handling DME is a bit tricky.  Just pouring it out of a bag it collects and bunches up and gets all sticky at the bag opening.  I'd probably divide it up into freezer bags, with 5 or 10 pounds in each, but I'd make sure I didn't do so on a humid day.

Comment: Luckily it's pretty dry here in Denver, but yeah, I can see it being a major problem in humid climes.

Answer (score 1):

You might put silica gel and/or oxygen absorber packets in there to help as well.

Answer (score 1):

We were buying LME from a Home Brew Supply in 33 lb containers.We saved the containers and use them for DME it holds 16 lb has a 2" opening, we fill with a funnel easy to pour out into container on scale works great