# gamma seal lids and B3 buckets

Tags: bucket, airtight

Last year, I bought lots of 6 gallon buckets for storing grain. They were from morebeer, and look like this [image: 6 gallon bucket]

The buckets do the job, but the lids are tricky to get on and off.

I'm thinking of buying [gamma seal lids](http://www.bayteccontainers.com/gamma-seal-lids.html) which look like they are easier to remove. As you can see in the photo, the morebeer buckets have some 'rings' near the top, I'm wondering if these interfere with the gamma seal adapter that goes on the bucket. Anyone successfully used a gamma seal lid with these buckets?

EDIT

while looking for a photo and link to gamma seals, I found this picture. 
[image: gamma seal]

The spacings of the rings on the bucket look very similar to the morebeer buckets. Since I plan to be buying 20 of these and shipping to Europe, I don't trust just eyeballing this, so I hope someone can confirm that they work on the B3 buckets.

Comment: What is a gamma seal lid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read this page:  http://www.bayteccontainers.com/gama-seal-lid-white.html

It has the following information: "Fits 3½,5 & 6 Gallon Buckets" and "THE GAMMA SEAL LID FITS STANDARD 12" DIAMETER PLASTIC PAILS."  and "AIRTIGHT Reseals Your Bucket or Pail Easy Opening Lid Fits All Universally Used 12" Opening Pails and Buckets"

So I would say if your pail is 12" in diameter you are probably safe here.  They seem to be designed to be pretty universal.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen something like this, but I keep forgetting to measure the bucket and I'm not at home now so I can't measure - do you know what diameter the morebeer buckets are?

Answer (score 1):

Your cheapest option is probably to just get a 5 gallon paint bucket lid opener from a hardware store.

Something like this:
[http://www.amazon.com/Linzer-5425-Plastic-5-Gallon-Opener/dp/B000KKPBFE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KKPBFE)

Comment: +1 Thanks, I didn't know about these. Just added one to my order from amazon. I have 30 buckets, 20 for grain, 10 planned as replacements when my current fermentors get too scratched. This will be very useful for getting the lids of those. Although, I'd still like to use gamma seals for my grain, if possible.

Comment: Are you worried about grain buckets getting scratched?

Comment: @brewchez - hehe, no, that would be seriously paranoid. but my existing plastic buckets I use for fermenting. Even with careful handling and pbw cleaning, I can still feel some scratches on the inside, so I expect to have to replace these soon. I plan to use 10 morebeer buckets as replacements for my existing buckets - gamma seals are not an option for fermenting, so I'm stuck with the morebeer lid, which is difficult to get on an off. the lid opener that HtMA posted will be a great help there.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [comment](http://forums.morebeer.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=38266#p400991) in a newsgroup about the B3 buckets

> I have 1 and the lid does not seal. I have since bought a gamma seal
>   lid that spins off. it is very air tight.

It seems they do fit.

It's simplicity itself that the mouths of buckets are all the same size. I don't think that's how it is here in Europe.

Comment: Got all the parts and can confirm that the gamma seals fit fine on the more beer buckets.